# How to write a custom "output function'' for the options structure in ode15s in MATLAB for storing history of solution vector?

Tags: matlab, ode

for my code

```
options=odeset('OutputFcn',@myfun)
    [T,Y]=ode15s(@(T,X)sys(T,X,vin),[t0 .0005],X(:,1),options)
    function Xdot = sys(T,X,vin)
    Xdot=A*X+B*U
    end
```

I don't know how to write function `myfun` to execute the `OutputFcn` to store the solution vector at each step.

Comment: Your solution vector is `Y`. Why not use that directly instead of trying to set up an output function? Also explore what the 'Refine' option does and what its default value is.

Comment: For printing the vector output at every time step maybe

Comment: Is the run really that slow? You also have the mechanism of `odextend` available that allows you to introduce pre-planned stops in the integration without losing much performance.

Comment: no it isn't.Thanks for clearing my doubts

Answer (score 0):

From the [`odeset` documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/odeset.html):

[image]

Comment: Yes I've seen this, I need help in writing the full custom output function for my program. I'm unable to write `status=myOutputFcn(t,y,flag)`for my program